# how to simplify web3 code to send ERC20 tokens using python?

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20, web3.py, pyethereum, buidler

Help, I need to simplify a transaction to send my erc20 tokens using this code as a reference from python web3, the problem is that the code is in a project that when I send my tokens a percentage of the amount is sent to the projects creator . for this reason I want to send without taxes directly.

this code works but i don't want to use third party projects for fear of getting scammed

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct
from web3 import Web3
import json, requests, time

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(''))
web3_2 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(''))

with open('token_abi.json') as f:
    token_abi = json.load(f)
token_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress("token contract address"), abi=token_abi)
token_contract_2 = web3_2.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress("token contract address"), abi=token_abi)

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36" }

def get_claimed_token(address):
    return int(token_contract_2.functions.balanceOf(address).call())

def get_unclaimed_token(address):
    for i in range(50):
        response = requests.get(f"provider", headers=headers, data="")
        if (response.status_code == 200): break
        time.sleep(1)
    if (response.status_code != 200):
        print(response.text)
    assert(response.status_code == 200)
    result = response.json()

    total = int(result["total"])
    last_claimed_item_at = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(result["last_claimed_item_at"]))

    if (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=-14) < last_claimed_item_at):
        total = 0

    return total

def execute_token_claim(claim, nonces):
    if (claim.state["signature"] == None):
        access_token = get_jwt_access_token(claim.address, claim.private_key)
        custom_headers = headers.copy()
        custom_headers["authorization"] = f"Bearer {access_token}"
        response = requests.post(f"https://", headers=custom_headers, json="")
        if (response.status_code != 200):
            print(response.text)
        assert(response.status_code == 200)
        result = response.json()["blockchain_related"]["signature"]

        claim.state["signature"] = result["signature"].replace("0x", "")

    nonce = nonces[claim.address]
    claim_txn = token_contract.functions.checkpoint(claim.address, result["amount"], result["timestamp"], claim.state["signature"]).buildTransaction({'gas': 1000000, 'gasPrice': 0, 'nonce': nonce})

    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(claim_txn, private_key = bytearray.fromhex(claim.private_key.replace("0x", "")))
    web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)

    nonces[claim.address] += 1

    return web3.toHex(web3.keccak(signed_txn.rawTransaction)) # Returns transaction hash.
def transfer_token(transaction, private_key, nonce):
    transfer_txn = token_contract.functions.transfer(
        transaction.to_address,
        transaction.amount).buildTransaction({
        'chainId': 2020,
        'gas': 100000,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('0', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })

    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transfer_txn, private_key = bytearray.fromhex(private_key.replace("0x", "")))
    web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    return web3.toHex(web3.keccak(signed_txn.rawTransaction)) # Returns transaction hash.
```

Comment: Did you try hiring someone to help you? Alternatively you could search in the site for other a python snippet that can be used to send ERC20 tokens.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.